# Azure DevOps checkout only triggered repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

I was trying to check out only the repository that triggers the pipeline.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo2
    type: git
    name: branching/repo2
    ref: dev
    trigger:
    - dev
  
  - repository: repo1
    type: git
    name: branching/repo1
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main
  
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- script: echo "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
- ${{ if in(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repo1') }}:
  - checkout: repo1
- ${{ if in(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repo2') }}:
  - checkout: repo2
```

But each time, this only checkout the source repository.

When the pipeline is triggered from repo1, I tried to checkout repo1, and when it is triggered from repo2, I tried to checkout repo2.

I don't want to keep changing the name of the checkout repository in the pipeline file.
Is there another way to have the checkout task choose the triggered repository automatically?

Comment: What the `echo...` printing?

Comment: The repository name by which the pipeline is triggered is printed in echo.

Answer (score 1):

Checking out multiple repos involve different ways of calling `checkout`:

1. Check out the triggering repo with: `checkout: self`
2. Check out the other repos with: `checkout: <reponame>`

More info and options using checkout see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#specify-multiple-repositories

### Edit

Assuming your trigger repo is repo1 or repo2, your YAML example would look like:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo2
    type: git
    name: branching/repo2
    ref: dev
    trigger:
    - dev
  
  - repository: repo1
    type: git
    name: branching/repo1
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main
  
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- script: echo "Triggered repo: $(Build.Repository.Name)"
- checkout: self
- ${{ if in(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repo1') }}:
  - checkout: repo2
- ${{ if in(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repo2') }}:
  - checkout: repo1
```

Comment: I don't want to keep changing the name of the checkout repository in the pipeline file.
Is there another way to have the checkout task choose the triggered repository automatically?

Comment: @divyammatia Updated my answer with an example

Comment: This soln not working

Comment: @divyammatia ok, let me try something else, I think some of my assumptions are not right. Where is yaml stored? Do you only want to trigger the dev / main from rep1 / rep2? And on triggering repo 1 you only want repo1, and not both?

Comment: yes , this is what exactly i want.